# javascript における多次元配列の初期化について

Tags: javascript

javascriptにおける4次元配列についての質問です。以下のコードは動作します。

```
var dimension4 = {
  map: [[[['4th dimension']]]],
  put: function() {
    console.log(this.map[0][0][0][0]);
  }
};

dimension4.put();
```

ですが以下のコードは動作しません。

```
var dimension4 =
 {
    map: [[[[]]]],
    ini: function()
    {
        var i, j, m, n;
        for (i = 0; i<8; i++) { for (j = 0; j<8; j++) {
                for (m = 0; m<8; m++) { for (n = 0; n<8; n++) {
                        this.map[i][j][m][n] = '0';
                }}
        }}
        return this.map;
    }
 };

 dimension4.ini();
```

テスト環境は firefox( fire-bug ) です。
TypeError: this.map[i][j][m] is undefined　が出力されます。何の問題もない初期化ルーチンのように私には見えます。どこに問題があるのでしょうかさっぱりわかりません。宜しくお願いします。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

一例として、`map` 関数を使って初期化する方法を参考までに載せておきます。

```
var dimension4 =
 {
    ini: function()
    {
      var arr = '0';
      for(var i=0;i<4;i++){
        arr = Array.apply(null, Array(8)).map(() => arr);
      }
      this.map = arr;
    }
 };
```

**追記**

見直してみて気が付いたのですが、上記のコードは `shallow copy` になっています。

```
dimension4.ini();
dimension4.map[0][0][0][0] = 1;

dimension4.map[0][0][1][0]
=> 1
dimension4.map[0][1][0][0]
=> 1
dimension4.map[1][0][0][0]
=> 1
```

つまり、配列の `reference`(参照)をコピーしています。

jQuery や Underscore.js にはオブジェクトを完全にコピーする(deep copy)メソッドがある様ですが、それらの代わりに `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arr))` を使います。

```
arr = Array.apply(null, Array(8))
           .map(() => JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arr)));

dimension4.map[0][0][0][0] = 1;
dimension4.map[0][0][1][0]
=> "0"
dimension4.map[0][1][0][0]
=> "0"
dimension4.map[1][0][0][0]
=> "0"
```

Comment: map[[[[]]]] としたことを反省させられました。早急にコード本体の方も maps[[[[]]]] に改めました。色々考えさせられる one liner です。

Answer (score 6):

途中のレベルの配列が未定義_undefined_ですね。美しくないですがこういうことをすればいいわけです。書き方はいろいろ試してみてください。

```js
var matrix4d = [],
    initializeValue = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
  matrix4d[i] = [];
  for (var j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
    matrix4d[i][j] = [];
    for (var k = 0; k < 8; k++) {
      matrix4d[i][j][k] = [];
      for (var l = 0; l < 8; l++) {
        matrix4d[i][j][k][l] = initializeValue;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: 調査して同様の回答も見つけていました。きちんと最後まで書いてみるものです。コード本体では採用させていただきます。

Answer (score -2):

反復処理の中で行っている下記のコード

```
                       this.map[i][j][m][n] = '0';
```

のthisが示すスコープの範囲をもう一度考えてみてください。
そのthisはグローバル領域の「map」という変数に対して、アクセスしようとしているように見えます。

Comment: デバッグモードでブレークポイントをつければ一瞬でわかりそうですね。

Comment: 習作のつもりで昔懐かしい STARTREK ゲームを javascript で書いています。this の値は大丈夫の様ですが、どうも甘く見ていたようで2～3千行かかってしまいそうです。this の問題も入口に立った処です。有難うございました。

Comment: thisの値はどう呼び出したかによって決まるので、`dimension4.ini()` として呼び出している今回の場合、ちゃんと `this === dimension4` になっています。

Comment: まさしくその通りでした。スコープを気にしましょうという話は取り下げます。